# Wakanda Enterprise V1.1.0 Debugger dislikes CryptoJS Sha256.js module

Tags: javascript, wakanda

I want to use the Wakanda Debugger but every time I access my webapp's page or log in or change pages, the Default Guest session trips up about 4 times on Sha256.js, but it is not even called or referenced in these pages. It makes the debugger unusable. Is anyone else having this problem, or know what might be going on? The webapp works fine without the debugger, and still functions correctly if I just keep clicking continue.

The image shows what happens if I just try to navigate to the url of the project. Multiple debugger tabs pop open. [image]

Comment: Could you provide a simple solution to try out your issue ?

Comment: I created a test solution with only this module as an RPC and was unable to reproduce the issue. I don't think the problem is with the CryptoJS Sha256.js file after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer. I was using an `include` statement to this javascript file in my `databaseName.js` file that defines the scope of the tables in the remote datastore. That `include` statement simply did not belong there.